# Gradle sync faild: Unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android

While creating android library in project  & creating new project in android studio 3.5.1 , I got the error as **Unable to find valid certification path to requested target**.
I have tried lots of solutions available on stack overflow eg.,set proxy but didn't worked for me.
I exactly didn't get the solution for this error.
If anyone has solution for this error please share.

My build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.poc1"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Do you have updated gradle version ??

Comment: do you install the android SDK and config the path?

Comment: Yes Piyush I already have updated gradle version 3.5.1.

Comment: @Lenoarod android sdk path is properly configured.

Comment: Hi guys,I am working at client location with the client network  & the above error is still same. Unable to solved it. I'm also tried with the setting proxy but not working. Can anyone give me the solution? Is this error is related to restricted network at client location?